# Cannot bind jar in xamarin, No packages found

Tags: java, c#, jar, xamarin

I am trying to bind to a very simple jar file in a xamarin android project, but I am getting the warning:

```
JARTOXML : warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class GetCerts : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: GetCerts : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8601: No packages found.
```

if I add the picasso-2.5.2.jar to the same bindings project, it is accessible perfectly, just as in the documentation for binding a jar from xamarin (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/)

the code in the jar is extremely simple:

```
package com.mgw;

import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

class GetCerts {
    public static X509Certificate  GetCert(byte[] bytes) throws Exception
    {
        CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
        return cert;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only to the bindings project

Comment: That has not helped.  I have now tried building with jdk6 and the error has changed.  Having removed the method call and all import statements, adding a new method `public static void DoSomething(){}` and repackaging, I now get the warning `warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class GetCerts : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GetCerts (wrong name: com/mgw/GetCerts)`

Comment: Having now removed the package definition, and simplified the code massively just to get the binding to work, I have java source that looks like `class GetCerts {
     public static boolean DoSomething()
 {
  return true;
 }
}` and compiled with jdk6, I now get the problem `warning BG8601: No packages found.` with the preceding warning `warning J2X9001: Couldn't load class GetCerts : java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the class was not public.  I changed the code to be:

```
package com.sage;

import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class GetCerts {
     public static X509Certificate  GetCert(byte[] bytes) throws Exception
     {
         CertificateFactory certFactory =          CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
         InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
         X509Certificate cert =  (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
         return cert;
     }

    public static boolean DoSomething()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

change the file name to match the class name, rebuilt using JDK6 and it all worked.

Note that the JDK version used to build the library should not be higher than that used by Xamarin or you may get issues.