# App for external barcode scanner(use USB port)

Tags: java, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, barcode-scanner, bindings-library

Update: came up with new error about the provided java class[image]
I have a tutorial for building an app for an external barcode scanner(use USB port) by using Java + provided Jar Library. I'm trying to build the same app by using the Xamarin.Forms and that Jar Library(through BindingsLibrary Project). However, I got an error
 "Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: " when I compiled my code. Does anybody have an idea about what I'm doing wrong?

This my java classes:
The USBScanFactory

```
     package com.unistrong.qrcode;

      import com.unistrong.pin.GOPOManager;

   public class USBQRscanFactory {
    private static USBQRscanFactory factory = new USBQRscanFactory();
    static boolean mIsScanContinue = false;
    private GOPOManager mGopoManager = GOPOManager.getInstance();
    private OnScanListener mScanListener;
    private QRScanManagerJNI qrScanManagerJNI;

    private USBQRscanFactory() {
    }

    public static USBQRscanFactory createInstance() {
        return factory;
    }

    public void init(OnScanListener onScanListener) {
        this.mGopoManager.Pin11_High();
        this.qrScanManagerJNI = new QRScanManagerJNI(onScanListener);
        this.qrScanManagerJNI.callbackInit();
    }

    public void enableAddKeyValue(int i) {
        QRScanManagerJNI.AddKeyValue(i);
    }

    public void open() {
        this.mGopoManager.Pin11_Low();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        QRScanManagerJNI.OpenDev();
    }

    public void powerOn() {
        this.mGopoManager.Pin11_High();
        this.mGopoManager.openPower5V_3V3();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void powerOff() {
        this.mGopoManager.Pin11_High();
        this.mGopoManager.closePower5V_3V3();
    }

    public void scan_start() {
        QRScanManagerJNI.QRScan();
    }
```

On ScanListener:

```
package com.unistrong.qrcode;

public interface OnScanListener {
    void scanReport(byte[] bArr);

    void statusReport(int i);
}
```

And here is my code on Xamain:

```
 public class OnScanListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnScanListener
        {

            H myH = new H();
            public void ScanReport(byte[] byteArray)
            {
                lock (myH)
                {
                    if (null != byteArray && byteArray.Length > 0)
                    {
                        myH.SendMessage(myH.ObtainMessage(0, byteArray));
                    }
                }
            }

            public void StatusReport(int i)
            {
                lock (myH)
                {
                    myH.SendEmptyMessage(i);
                }

            }


        }

        #endregion
        public MainPage()
        {
            usbScan = USBQRscanFactory.CreateInstance();


            InitializeComponent();

        }







        int count = 0;
        private void scanBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            //usbScan.Init(OnScanListener);
            OnScanListener myOnScanListener = new OnScanListener();
            usbScan.PowerOn();
            usbScan.Init(myOnScanListener);
            Barcode.Text = "";

            openScanner(true);
            usbScan.Scan_start();
        }



        //Open Scanner
        private void openScanner(bool open)
        {
            if (open == mWorkingStateFlag) return;
            if (open)
            {
                try
                {
                    Java.Lang.Thread.Sleep(50);
                    usbScan.Open();
                    usbScan.EnableAddKeyValue(0);
                }
                catch (Java.Lang.InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.PrintStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: If you specify the scanner vendor and model number, the library/SDK name and specifications etc. provided, it will be easy to get an answer.

Comment: Is this the SDK to use? [DOWNLOAD Scanner_SDK_v1.2.6.zip](https://www.handheldgroup.com/support-rugged-computers/knowledgebase-KB/25495/) And did you try to inquire here? [Contact a Handheld office for rugged computer information](https://www.handheldgroup.com/about-us/contact-us/) And, maybe, these articles may be helpful. [Dedicated Barcode Scanners in Xamarin Forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/134048/dedicated-barcode-scanners-in-xamarin-forms), [Barcode Scanners Simplified](https://medium.com/@mypascal2000/barcode-scanners-simplified-1a4fb7ef621b)

Comment: Also, these articles may be helpful. [Xamarin forms with Andorid Binding (.jar) [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53496888/9014308), [Cannot bind jar in xamarin, No packages found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33479201/9014308), [working with jar and so files in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40485639/9014308), [Binding a Java Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/), [Introduction to DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes I took a look on their SDK + tutorial. However, it seems like they dont want to provide a complete library. In that jar file, there are important classes that are missing. That's why I got an issue when used that jar file and followed their instruction

Comment: How about considering trying these libraries instead of vendor's .jar file? [XamarinUsbSerial](https://bitbucket.org/lusovu/xamarinusbserial/src/default/)/[How to write to serial port?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69791/how-to-write-to-serial-port), [Xamarin.Android.SerialPort 1.0.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.SerialPort/), [anotherlab/UsbSerialForAndroid](https://github.com/anotherlab/UsbSerialForAndroid), [Jddl/Xamarin.Android.SerialPort](https://github.com/Jddl/Xamarin.Android.SerialPort)

Comment: Thanks for your time and advice.But I'm not sure the vendor allows me to do that or not. Have tried to add few more class to that jar over the last few days and now I'm able to compile the code,but got some error from the Jar. I updated my question to show that error. Do you have any idea about that error?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only a shallow knowledge of C# on the Windows desktop, so the details of your problem are unlikely to help. In fact, the above comments just introduce the search results with some relevant keywords.